# Checking if tab exists in tabControl c#

Tags: c#

I am creating tabs dynamically and I have managed to do it but when I try and make it check if the tab already exists so it cant add another one if just keeps adding them.

```
      private void fourBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theName = "Level4";
        TabPage tp = new TabPage(theName);
        if (!tp.Name.Equals(theName)) {




            tp.Name = theName;
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);

            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            tb.Multiline = true;
            tp.Controls.Add(tb); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to check if a TabPage exists with the same name...

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(tabPage)
```

What you currently do is, you create a new TabPage with a name, and check if that tab name does not have the same name which was and always will evaluate to `true` since you've literally given it that name.

```
private void fourBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 string theName = "Level4";
 TabPage tp = new TabPage(theName);
 if (!tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(tabPage2)) {

  tp.Name = theName;
  tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);

  TextBox tb = new TextBox();
  tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  tb.Multiline = true;
  tp.Controls.Add(tb);
 }
}
```

If you wish, you can even create a loop:

```
foreach(TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages){
   if(tab.Name == tabName)
      return true;
}
```

Comment: Iv'e tried using f (!tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(tabPage2)) but it comes up with the name tabPage2 does not exist in current context

Comment: Well, it doesn't exist in the context... Change `tabPage2` to `tp`.

Comment: I have that still lets the program continue adding the same tab

Comment: Try using the for loop then. Seems like youre doing something wrong.

Comment: Nope still no luck :L